# Specifying the precision when printing a float/double in C using printf

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, double, format-specifiers

I wanted to create a function that would print my array of doubles using a specified floating point precision as an argument to the function.
Let's say i have the following code:

```
void printDoubleArrayPrecision(int length, double *arr, int precision) {
    printf("[");
    if (length > 0) {
        printf("%.2lf", arr[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            printf(",%.2lf", arr[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Is there any way of replacing the 2 in `printf(",%.2lf", arr[i]);` with the given argument `precision`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a possibility in `printf`:

```
printf("%.*lf", precision, arr[i]);
```

will print `arr[i]` with the given precision.

Comment: Note: the `"l"` in `"%.*lf"` is optional here.  Use it or not, whatever brings more clarity to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently i should've searched for my solution by looking for printing strings with variable length instead of doubles.
A solution for my question would be:

```
printf(",%.*lf", precision, arr[i]);
```